# Is it possible to create mesh3d objects without indices information?

Tags: r, plotly, mesh, rgl

I have a matrix of landmarks that denotes a nose. I wish to convert this matrix to mesh3d so that I could use `shade3d` function to visualize the surface.

[Here](https://github.com/Patricklv/Nose-data) is the dput of my data. I have to deposit it in GitHub because it is too large to be directly put here.

The three columns are x, y, and z coordinates. I would like to ask how can I convert this matrix to mesh3d. I tried `as.mesh3d`, however, I was returned error because the number of vertices is not a multiple of 3 or 4.

```
mesh.d <- as.mesh3d(deformed, triangles = T)
```

Error in as.mesh3d.default(deformed, triangles = T) :
length(x)%%3 == 0 is not TRUE

I also tried to remove the last two rows so that my data has 621 rows, which is a multiple of 3. I then used `shade3d` to plot. However, the resultant plot does not give surface mesh of a nose. The function `mesh3d` requires input of not just vertices, but also indices which I do not have. I therefore ask if it is possible to convert my coordinate matrix to an object of mesh3d in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indices describe the triangles formed from triplets of vertices.  If you don't have them given to you, you will need to construct them somehow.

There are a few options.  You can use the `alphashape3d::ashape3d` function to approximate the outline of the points.  You need to choose the `alpha` parameter; for example, with `alpha = 20` I get

```
ash <- ashape3d(as.matrix(nose), alpha=20)
shade3d(as.mesh3d(ash))
```

[image: screenshot]

This would work even if the points were randomly rearranged, but in fact, if you plot

```
plot3d(nose, type = "l")
```

you can see that the points are very regularly organized:

[image: screenshot2]

If you can work out how they are organized, you might be able to rearrange the x, y and z coordinates into matrices and use `surface3d()` to plot them.  For example, this plots all but the first 23 points:

```
m1x <- matrix(nose[24:323,1], nrow=20)
m1y <- matrix(nose[24:323,2], nrow=20)
m1z <- matrix(nose[24:323,3], nrow=20)
m2x <- matrix(nose[324:623,1], nrow=20)
m2y <- matrix(nose[324:623,2], nrow=20)
m2z <- matrix(nose[324:623,3], nrow=20)
mx <- cbind(m1x[,15:1], m2x)
my <- cbind(m1y[,15:1], m2y)
mz <- cbind(m1z[,15:1], m2z)
library(rgl)
open3d()
surface3d(mx, my, mz, col = "gray")
```

[image: screenshot3]

You can see that the `alpha3d` plot fills out the side of the nose too much.  However, this one ignores 23 points; I can't really see how they should be incorporated.

Answer (score 1):

The result is not too bad with the *Advanced front surface reconstruction*, available in the [SurfaceReconstruction package](https://github.com/stla/SurfaceReconstruction) (not on CRAN).

```
library(SurfaceReconstruction)
mesh <- AFSreconstruction(nose)

library(rgl)
shade3d(mesh, color = "pink")
```

[image]